# Sitecore - Hide a rendering if a placeholder is empty

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I have a fairly simple Sitecore MVC rendering which contains a heading field and a placeholder:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="m-header"><span>@Html.Sitecore().Field("PromoItemsHeader")</span></h2>

        <div class="l-section grid">
            @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("PromoItems")
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I would like this rendering to display outside of page-editing mode *only* if the placeholder contains items. This seems like it should be simple to do but I can't find an obvious / clean way of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sitecore.Context.Page.Renderings
    .Count(r => r.Placeholder.IndexOf("PromoItems", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

If you would like to have only renderings with a data source, you could add this:

```
Sitecore.Context.Page.Renderings
    .Where(r => r.Placeholder.IndexOf("PromoItems", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
    .Count(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Settings.DataSource))
```

I would now simply add a new property to your view model which returns if the placeholder contains any renderings.

Answer (score 5):

`Sitecore.Context.Page.Renderings` is what I've used in a previous Sitecore 7.x webforms project, but it didn't seem to work for me in Sitecore 8.x MVC + Glass land - the Renderings collection was always empty inside my layout views. Not sure if that's an 8.x thing, a Glass thing or an "I've screwed up my project somehow" thing.

What did work was:

```
var pageContext = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.Current;
var pageDefinition = pageContext.PageDefinition;
bool showSidebar = pageDefinition.Renderings.Any(x => x.Placeholder == "left");
```